# Read Vector Data from C++ dll?

Tags: c++, list, delphi, dll

I got a problem with reading data from a C++ dll.I have to proccee data in C++ dll and my UI writing by Delphi.I want to pass the TList to the dll ,then dll insert some data into the list.Is there any way to make it? Example better ,best regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @Victoria Wut??

Comment: @Victoria You should probably read my profile thoroughly again.

Comment: TList is not compatible with vector, you can not pass TList to the dll. Describe real problem, C++ compiler, and show C++ dll export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a Delphi-specific type like `TList` to a C++ DLL, unless that DLL was written in C++Builder.

The C++ compiler won't be able to handle your Delphi-specific type TList (nor any other class, dynamic array, string, set, open array, etc.). And Delphi is not able to handle C++ `vector` types (or any other template or class types). **So simply don't do it**.

Even if your DLL was written in C++Builder of the same version as the Delphi compiler, which knows about `TList`, you will still have problems because you are dealing with two different instances of the RTL, so many things won't work properly either (memory management, RTTI, etc.).

And note that C++Builder packages are not a solution either: Delphi can't use BPLs written in C++Builder. C++Builder can use Delphi packages, though.

So just pass plain old data (POD) types. Pass arrays of simple types or structs/records of simple types, and pass the arrays as pointers (to the first element). Do not try to pass dynamic arrays or open array parameters. These are Delphi-specific again.

You *can* use a dynamic array on the Delphi side, as long as you just pass a pointer to the first element, and you allocated enough room for the DLl to fill it. Don't let the DLL manage memory or try to reallocate the array. it can't. Pass the maximum length of the data along, as an extra parameter. The DLL should only *fill* the array, no more.

---

*For what it's worth, I have written an article about **[DLL dos and don'ts](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html)**. Please read and heed it. The article explains in a little more detail what I wrote above, and a little more about writing DLLs to be used across language boundaries.*